# why pandas picking wrong google account

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, pandasql

Hi I am using below code to reach bigquery

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

query = """
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [zz_marketing_analytics.sr_channel_cost]
where new_business_goal = 'ACQ'
"""

project_id = 'stone-outpost-636'

data_df = pd.read_gbq(query,project_id)
```

Its giving me error

> pandas.io.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: accessDenied, Message: Access Denied: Project stone-outpost-636: The user xyz@gmail.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project stone-outpost-636.

Since its using wrong account its not able to reach the big query. Any idea how to reset it and make big query ask me for the correct account permission. Cause this started happening as by mistake i game permission to my private google acoount. Any way to reset it?

Comment: you will need to refresh [aplication default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

Comment: Please read How the Application Default Credentials work under [aplication default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

Comment: Actually I found the issue. Somehow the login is connected to each python file and the same code works fine if I copy paste it in another python file. The other file is picking up my correct google account